# не отправляет письма(smtp.yandex.ru) wordpress + IIS

Tags: wordpress, email, iis, smtp

Поднял wordpress на IIS.
Настроил почту для домена на pdd.yandex.ru
Сконфигурил wordpress на настройки smtp.yandex.ru

```
port 465
SSL= true
smtp auth = true
credentials : ******
```

пробовал так ->

```
port 25
SSL= none
smtp auth = true
credentials : ******
```

Создал правило для firewall на отправку  на сервере, telnet-ом походил по smtp серверам отдает ответы smtp.gmail.com 587 и smtp.yandex.ru 25. в логах ничего нет, при  отправке тестового письма wordpress пишет  connection failed.
I need help!

Comment: Решено.
По умолчанию функция mail() на PHP с Windows не работает.
Необходимо установить SMTP сервер на IIS, и сконфигурировать php.ini
<code>
      SMTP = localhost
      smtp_port = 25
      sendmail_from = email_kotoriy_budet_otpravitelem@mail.ru
<code>